# Android - Changing button height it is stretched

Tags: android, button, height

I have a button with an image. The height of the image should be the 20% of the height of the device. So I set the height of the image programmatically.
The problem is that, if i do it, the image becomes stretched. I put the settings that it has to be scaled centerinside and I have tried also with other elements, as imagebutton or imageview, but I had always the same problem.
How can I do?

**UPDATE**
This is my xml code:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/letterLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:onClick="onClick">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/letterButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:clickable="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And my Java code where i set the height:

```
        letterLayout.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (hQdr);
        letterTest.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (hQdr);
        //letterTest.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (wQdr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with the parameter `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`? This Crops your Image to enter in the layout

Comment: I tried with all the possibile scaletypes, but it is always stretched

Comment: can you post your layout code? Why don't you try to set the height with a ´weight´ 1/5 in the XML

Comment: I added my code up, in the update. I have to set the height of button in java because it depends on the device height